# Limited number of geoms in ggforce?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

Trying to plot several circles in one dataset, seems that 10 is the max number of circles. How can I plot more than 10 circles?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

circles <- data.frame(
  x0 = rep(1:3, 10),
  y0 = rep(1:3, each = 10),
  r = seq(0.1, 1, length.out = 30)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r = r, fill = r), data = circles) +
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: I do not find the maximum number of circles is 10. I can quite easily setup data that allows me to plot 30+ circles. Do you care to expand on what the problem is exactly?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The circles were drown one on top of the other, the largest obscuring the others. Once I defined r = rev(r) I could see them all