# Plotting order of circles in ggforce

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I am revising a problem I posted prevously [Limited number of geoms in ggforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66314122/3923280). I thought then that I was mistaken but I can now reconstruct it more clearly:
I would like to plot N circles one on top of the other. No matter how many circles I want to plot, circle #11-N are plotted underneath the first 10 circles. This demonstartes the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

circles <- data.frame(
  x0 = seq(1, 30),
  y0 = seq(1, 30),
  r = 2
)

ggplot() +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r = r), fill = "grey", data = circles) +
  coord_fixed()
```

Therefore when I would like to plot concentric circles, the first 10 circles hide all the rest.
I can code a workaround by first plotting the 11-N circles and then the first ten but its not elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in `ggforce`: it groups the points in the circles with strings that don't sort into the same order as the original circles.

To get a version that fixes the bug, use

```
remotes::install_github("dmurdoch/ggforce@sortorder")
```

This will require you to have package build tools installed.  If you don't have those, you could watch the web site https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/224 to see when the fix gets incorporated into the CRAN build of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer a slightly hacky workaround that may not perform very well for large datasets. Loop through each of the rows creating a single circle then add them all together to make a single object to plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

circles <- data.frame(
    x0 = seq(1, 30),
    y0 = seq(1, 30),
    r = 2
) 

mygeom_circle <- function(onerow) {
    geom_circle(aes(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r = r), fill = "grey", data = onerow) 
}

gs <- sapply(1:nrow(circles), function(r) mygeom_circle(circles[r,])) # loop through one by one making single circles
gg <- 
    ggplot() +
    gs +            # add the single circles in the order they were made
    coord_fixed()

gg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but as its is a bug, I prefer to use the fix